# MySQL determining which database to use

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner with MySQL.  I have this code and I would like an explanation on how the function knows which database to use since $conn and $db are defined?

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","primeb5_mysql","***");
$db = mysql_select_db("primeb5_unigis");
$query = "SELECT * FROM lesson3";
$result = mysql_query($query);"
```

Comment: If you would like to start using php+mysql I recommend you to use MySQLi or PDO modules... mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: There is only one database defined, and that is in the `mysql_select_db()` function. `mysql_connect()` only contains the database host, username and password. Aside from that, [please don't use mysql_* functions anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: just query like this    SELECT columns FROM database.table ...

Comment: mysql_query uses the last connection if not given by explicit argument `mysql_query($query, $db)`. You should listen to @NelsonGaldemanGraziano however and not use the mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 3):

From PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the
>   last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed.

So, In case you don't specify the connection (second parameter) to the `mysql_query()` function, **the last one is used.**

On the side note, I'd like to notify you, that `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. Do not use them, because if you do, your site might stop working soon.

Comment: And I know it's annoying, but please do include the warning that this is deprecated!

Comment: Just meant to do so! :) Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead**

You don't have to use an PHP function to select your database

just use this

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM primeb5_unigis.lesson3");
```

or join example between multiple databases after ON missing...

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM database1.table1 INNER JOIN database2.table2 ON ...");
```

**edit**

i think topicstarter means connection to database but i leave the answer could be helpfull

Comment: you mean mysql is deprecated not mysqli is deprecated

Comment: thanks indeed typing error..